# Flot graph, mysql and weeknumbers

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following code to display the income by month. I want to use similar data but then grouped by week(numbers).

My question: Is there a more elegant way to make a shorter query, other than modify the query below? Do I have to use 52 subqueries to calculate income by week, instead of 12 subqueries by month?

```
    SELECT
      IfNull(Year,'Totals') Year,
      `Jan`,`Feb`,`Mar`,`Apr`,`May`,`Jun`,`Jul`,`Aug`,`Sep`,`Oct`,`Nov`,`Dec`,Qty AS Totaal
    FROM (
     SELECT
     year(orders.Order_date) AS 'Year',
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 1, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Jan,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 2, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Feb,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 3, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Mar,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 4, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Apr,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 5, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as May,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 6, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Jun,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 7, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Jul,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 8, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Aug,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)= 9, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Sep,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)=10, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Oct,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)=11, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as Nov,
      sum(if(month(Order_date)=12, (order_create.amount * order_create.prices), 0)) as `Dec`,
      ROUND(SUM(order_create.amount * order_create.prices))),2) AS Qty
    FROM
      order_create
      INNER JOIN orders ON (order_create.order_ID = orders.order_ID)
    GROUP BY year
    ) sums ;
```